# How to use Selector2?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Is there any example of using this Selector2 in Provider package ?.I can't find any documentation on how to use this

```
Selector2<ModelA,ModelB, bool>(
   selector: (_, modelA,modelB) {
   return modelA.isLoading; //I don't know how to return this
},
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. What doesn't work with the code you gave?

Comment: I'm sorry my question isn't clear, So the question is, how do I get the bool value from 2 models

Comment: I just found the workaround. I just use the tuple package to get the value from 2 models. Feel free to edit If I'm wrong

Answer (score 3):

I just found a workaround like this

```
Selector2<ModelA,ModelB,Tuple2<bool,bool>>(
  selector : (_,modelA,modelB) => Tuple2(modelA.isLoading,modelB.isLoading),
  builder : ...
)
```

import tuple package first before using this

Answer (score 0):

I found documentation on it right [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Selector2-class.html)

Comment: my question is, how do I return the value of selector from 2 models ? @Tony